# Creating/updating new field with random match from multiple matches in second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, many-to-one

I have a dataframe Counties:

```
CountyID     CountyName     SalesRep     FiscalQuarter     Sales
185           Cuyahoga       Winslow      2Q19             4,564
276           Waterton       Smith        1Q17             900
```

And a second dataframe CountyZips with County IDs and all the zip codes it contains:

```
CntyID     Zip
185          05643
185          05617
185          05866
276          32786
276          33465
276          34119
```

I want to either update the first dataframe with new "zip" column or make new dataframe with that zip column, and populate the "zip" field with a random match from the second dataframe's Zip column.  In other words, there are multiple zips associated with one county ID in the second dataframe; I'd like to just get one of them (not first or last, but random, which could technically be first or last, I just want it to not ALWAYS be first or last, and I don't want to specify 3rd, 4th, etc. match because sometimes there might be just be one match, or no match).  So, my desired result (either dataframe 1 updated or new dataframe):

```
CountyID     Zip     CountyName     SalesRep     FiscalQuarter     Sales
185          05617   Cuyahoga       Winslow      2Q19             4,564
276          34119   Waterton       Smith        1Q17             900
```

Note that the zips were updated with a random zip from dataframe 2 where County ID matches between both datasets.

I found one seemingly applicable answer to this on a previous question, where solution was:

```
d1[d2, on = .(gender, year, code),
  {ri <- sample(.N, 1L)
  .(amount = amount[ri], status = status[ri])}, by = .EACHI]
```

And I tried this, modifying dataframe and field names as appropriate (and I a matching on only one field, not 3), but all attempts got syntax error, including when I made dataframes and fields and data that matched those in the original question, so I'm not sure if this a python versioning issue or not (I'm using Python 3.7.4)

If anyone can help me with this I'd appreciate it.  Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
import random

df['Zip'] = df['CountyID'].map(zip_df.groupby('CntyID')['Zip'].agg(list)).apply(random.choice)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   CountyID CountyName SalesRep FiscalQuarter  Sales    Zip
0       185   Cuyahoga  Winslow          2Q19  4,564   5617
1       276   Waterton    Smith          1Q17    900  32786
```

The step:

```
map(zip_df.groupby('CntyID')['Zip'].agg(list))
```

creates a list of possible choices for each county, then:

```
.apply(random.choice)
```

chooses one randomly. If you want to select always the same *zip* for the same *county*, use:

```
import random
lookup = zip_df.groupby('CntyID')['Zip'].agg(lambda x: random.choice(x.tolist()))
df['Zip'] = df['CountyID'].map(lookup)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   CountyID CountyName SalesRep FiscalQuarter  Sales    Zip
0       185   Cuyahoga  Winslow          2Q19  4,564   5617
1       276   Waterton    Smith          1Q17    900  32786
```

Comment: Amazing, that did it.  Thank you very much, I don't regret the time I tried to make it work before asking, but wow, it's very exciting to do something and see it work.  One question; I get Python feedback upon execution of this:

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Is this some kind of best practice thing and I should do a different way, for instance creating new dataframe instead of updating existing one?

Comment: IMHO is generally better to create a new DataFrame if you look at the pandas functions, must of them will create a new DataFrame by default.